# how to create and call a custom function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I need to create a simple function in jQuery which will call within other few functions

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function reload_cart() {
    alert('reload cart called');
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  reload_cart(); //i need to call from here.
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.add_to_cart').live('click', function (e) {
    reload_cart(); //i need to call from here.
  });
});
```

The error I get in firebug: `reload_cart() is not defined`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`reload_cart` is local to your first `$(document).ready()` callback. You can't call it from an outside scope.

You should merge your functions together:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function reload_cart() {
        alert('reload cart called');
    }

    reload_cart();

    $('a.add_to_cart').live('click', function(e) {
        reload_cart();
    });
});
```

An even better solution would be to create a `cart` object, add `reload` to its prototype, and initialize it outside of all of the callbacks.

Comment: thanks for your fast response. may i have a sample code of how do i create cart object and call it from anywhere. i don't have any experience of prototype much.

Comment: MDN has very nice articles on these subjects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 8):

Yes, because you declared the function within the scope of the first `$(document).ready(function(){})` so it will not be available outside of that functions scope.

I am not sure why you would call `$(document).ready()` more than once. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function reload_cart() {
       alert('reload cart called');
   }

   reload_cart(); //i need to call from here.


   $('a.add_to_cart').live('click', function(e) {
       reload_cart(); //i need to call from here.
   });
});
```

Alternatively you can also declare your function outside of `$(document).ready()` and it will be globally available.

Answer (score 7):

Put your function definition:

```
function reload_cart() {
    alert('reload cart called');
}
```

Outside document.ready.

Currently, Its scoped inside the document.ready handler only.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//reload_cart is only available here
    function reload_cart() {
        alert('reload cart called');
    }
});
```